# Proof existence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx$ - is this proof correct?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to show that the integral
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx $$
exists.

My approach: Let $b > 1$, then the integral
$$ \int_1^b \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx $$
exists because
$$
0 < \int_1^b \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \underbrace{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}_{\leq \frac{1}{x^2}} \,\mathrm dx \leq \int_1^b \frac{1}{x^{5/2}} \,\mathrm dx = \left.-\frac{2}{3} x^{-3/2} \right|_1^b = \underbrace{-\frac{2}{3} b^{-3/2}}_{\xrightarrow{b \to \infty}{0}} + \frac{2}{3} \xrightarrow{b \to \infty} \frac{2}{3}.
$$
Let $0 < \epsilon < 1$, then
$$ \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \underbrace{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}_{<1} \,\mathrm dx < \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \,\mathrm dx = \left.2 \sqrt x \right|_\epsilon^1 = 2(1 - \sqrt \epsilon) \xrightarrow{\epsilon \searrow 0} 2 $$
and in total
$$ 0 < \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx}_{\leq 2} + \underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx}_{\leq \frac{2}{3}} \leq 2 + \frac{2}{3}. $$

Is this a proper proof?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's fine. There's only one addendum worth giving in an answer. Let $f(x):=\frac{x^{-1/2}}{1+x^2}$. You've argued that, because$$A(\epsilon):=\int_{\epsilon}^1f(x)dx,\,B(b):=\int_1^b g(x)dx\implies\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}A(\epsilon)\in[0,\,2],\,\lim_{b\to\infty}B(b)=\in[0,\,\tfrac23],$$the integral exists as $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}A(\epsilon)+\lim_{b\to\infty}B(b)$. This is a valid proof, but does more work than you need to. Proofs normally verify $A(0),\,B(\infty)$ exist within finite bounds, without having to consider these limits.

Comment: But how could I have shown only existence of these limits here?

Comment: @Thomas For example, $0\le\int_0^1f(x)dx\le\int_0^1x^{-1/2}dx=2$ implies $\int_0^1f(x)dx\in\Bbb R$ exists.

Comment: Huh? Isn't that exactly what I do in the second step? With the difference that I consider $\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} \int_\epsilon^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx$ as a limit and you consider directly $\int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @Thomas *Exactly*. You can use the limit if you want to, but there's no need.

Comment: Okay, good! I used the limit because I applied the definition directly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, here is another approach :

\begin{aligned}&\bullet \ f:x\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+x\right)}\textrm{ is continuous on }\left(0,+\infty\right)\cdot\\ &\bullet \ \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x^{\frac{3}{4}}}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+x\right)}}=0\textrm{, and thus }f\left(x\right)=\underset{\overset{x\to 0}{}}{\mathcal{o}}\left(x^{-\frac{3}{4}}\right)\textrm{, and }x\mapsto x^{-\frac{3}{4}}\textrm{ is integrable on }\left(0,a\right]\textrm{ for}\\ &\textrm{any }a\in\left(0,+\infty\right) \cdot\\ &\bullet \ \lim_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+x\right)}}=0\textrm{, thus }f\left(x\right)=\underset{\overset{x\to +\infty}{}}{\mathcal{o}}\left(x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)\textrm{, and }x\mapsto x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\textrm{ is integrable on }\left[a,+\infty\right)\\ &\textrm{for any }a\in\left(0,+\infty\right) \cdot \end{aligned}

Thus, our $ f $ is integrable on $ \left(0,+\infty\right)\cdot $